# run dart script from firestore cloud functions

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a flutter application thats generate a pdf with flutter pdf package.

I want to automate the process of generating the **exact** pdfs every "month" for example. hence, thought of using the same pdf generation function I already wrote in my app in cloud function that will be called with google tasks.

how can I define and run dart environment and script with firestore cloud functions

Comment: Did you see https://dart.dev/server/google-cloud?

Comment: I don't agree that this question is a duplicate of what is linked there, could not write the answer, so writing it here.
I have succeeded to do so by compiling the dart to linux exe and upload it together with functions, in JS function I called exec(<my exe>,...)

Answer (score 2):

At this date you can only run JavaScript, TypeScript or Python code on Cloud Functions. Consequently, you shall convert it to one of those languages.

You can use the **[Dart compile to JS compiler](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#js)** to convert and generate JS code from you Dart code.

```
dart compile js
```

Beware that this compiles your Dart code to deployable JavaScript, which may not always be compatible with NodeJs.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I have async functions in my dart file. compiling to JS did not help to wait for those async functions and my code did not run correctly, so I though there should be simpler ways.
I have tried to make it exec with dart compile exe --target-os  linux and run it on cloud, that worked, but when I need external packages I could not fine away to include those packages

Comment: Indeed, if your code depends on external libraries which are not pure Dart or which cannot be compiled and linked to the generated JS you will not be able to use this solution...